# How to collapse NavBar onSelect or onClick

Tags: react-bootstrap

I am using:
 `'react-bootstrap'`

```
handleMouseDown(e){
 // HOW TO
}
```

```
  <Navbar brand='React-Bootstrap' inverse toggleNavKey={0} onClick={this.handleMouseDown}>
    <Nav right eventKey={0}> {/* This is the eventKey referenced */}
...
  </div>
```

All works but the NavBar is not collapsing, du you know how to make it collapse when selected?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by wrapping the entire header in my own component and then maintaining state to hide or show the menu. Then you can just hook into the props of the navbar to show/hide and the onToggle lets you add your own function to set state with.

Example:

```
<Navbar inverse fixedTop toggleNavKey={0} navExpanded={this.state.navExpanded} onToggle={() => this.toggleNav()}>
```

Hope this helps. If you need more sample code let me know.